# Join three table in MySQL and get one row per id (one row per each entity in first table)

Tags: mysql, sql, join, spring-data-jpa

i have three table for products, product configs(eg iPhone x 64 black, iPhone x 64 red) and product inventories; I want to select all products and sort by price (in config table) and availability (in inventory table) but get only one row per product; how can id do this?
below is my mysql table structure

```
CREATE TABLE `product_inventories` (
  `inventory_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `quantity` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `warehouse_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `config_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `product_configs` (
  `config_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `product_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` decimal(12,3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `discount_percent` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sku` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=FIXED;

CREATE TABLE `products` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `category_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;
```

i tried this query :

```
SELECT * 
FROM products 
    LEFT JOIN product_configs ON products.id = product_configs.product_id 
    LEFT JOIN product_inventories inventories ON inventories.inventory_id =
         (SELECT product_inventories.inventory_id from product_inventories
          WHERE product_inventories.config_id = product_configs.config_id
          ORDER by product_inventories.quantity DESC LIMIT 1 ) 
ORDER BY product_configs.price ASC, inventories.quantity DESC
```

**edit:**
with this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM products 
    LEFT JOIN product_configs ON products.id = product_configs.product_id 
    LEFT JOIN product_inventories inventories ON inventories.inventory_id =
         (SELECT product_inventories.inventory_id from product_inventories
          WHERE product_inventories.config_idd = product_configs.config_id
          ORDER by product_inventories.quantity DESC LIMIT 1 ) 

ORDER BY product_configs.price is null, product_configs.price ASC, inventories.quantity DESC
```

i have below result; but i want one product per config with min price and max quantity
[image: query result]

Comment: `how can id do this?`... by writing a SQL query.  Stack Overflow is not a free code writing/homework service.  If you want help here, you will have to show some effort.

Comment: Please add your query

Comment: @JoeTaras query was added;

Comment: In your query there is an error : "WHERE  ORDER BY" Did you forgot the where clause ? (unrelated with the question though)

Comment: @JulienB. edited;

Comment: If i summarize you want min price and max quantity for each product id right ? Did you try a group by ?

Comment: @JulienB. exactly; yes i tried group by but the selected price is not min price;

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
SELECT 
    ...,
    SUM(quantity) AS total_quantity
FROM products AS p
    LEFT JOIN product_configs AS pc ON pc.product_id = p.id
    LEFT JOIN product_inventories AS pi ON pi.config_id = pc.config_id
GROUP BY p.id
ORDER BY pc.price ASC, pi.quantity DESC
```

Comment: Thanks but this is not correct; because i want the configs that has low price and available(quantity in inventory table grater than zero) ; but your query will return the configs with low price even quantity of config is zero

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, see if it will work:

`SELECT *,MIN(price),MAX(quantity) 
FROM products 
    LEFT JOIN product_configs ON products.id = product_configs.product_id 
    LEFT JOIN product_inventories inventories ON inventories.inventory_id =
    (SELECT product_inventories.inventory_id FROM product_inventories INNER JOIN product_configs ON 
    product_inventories.config_id = product_configs.config_id
    ORDER BY product_inventories.quantity DESC LIMIT 1 ) 
    GROUP BY sku
ORDER BY product_configs.price ASC, inventories.quantity DESC;`

Note that I still retain `SELECT *` and added `min(price),max(quantity)` at the end so you can do the comparison. If this is not working for you, you may need to provide some data example and an illustration of how your desired output is.

Comment: thanks ; post edited and some extra information was added